# c++ chrono storing time_point expression must be modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++-chrono

I am trying to store a time point like so

```
class Lap {
public:
Lap() : 
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = clock::now(); //works fine
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); //compilation error
}

private:
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start; //variable to store time_point
};
```

However I get a compilation when trying to set the value of start

> std::chrono::time Lap::start expression must be modifiable lvalue

Why is my expression not a modifiable lvalue and how do I store an instance of a time_point?

Answer (score 0):

Code works, fine I had a method was the name `start` that was causing me issues.